# .Net Core Visual Studio project command line build same as right-clicking build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, command-line, build

I would like to be able to run a batch command to build my C# .NET Core project the exact same way that it builds when I right click the project in the solution and select build in Visual Studio.

I have tried the following

```
dotnet build
dotnet build --configuration Debug
dotnet build --no-restore
dotnet build --no-dependencies
```

and a mixture of the above, none of them seem to build the project in the same way that right-clicking on the project and selecting build does. Can someone point me in the direction or does anyone know the commands to run to build **the exact same way** that right-clicking the project builds?

Comment: **the exact same way** What is missing after using the command `build`? I executed the "build batch command" in the project directory, and it built as normal. How did you run batch command to build the project?

Comment: Presumably the same way as you where I navigate to the project folder in an administrator command prompt and type the command(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main issue that I faced here was that I was trying to build a WPF with the dotnet command line tool. In order to keep the same configuration build as my solution I had to run **msbuild** directly instead of using **dotnet** below is the code that I used to solve this problem

```
SET SolutionPath=%1

@ECHO OFF
CLS

ECHO ------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO Building WPF UI Project
ECHO ------------------------------------------------------------
cd %SolutionPath%
msbuild MySolution.sln -t:MySolution_WPF_UI -p:Configuration=Debug -p:Platform="x64" -p:WarningLevel=0 - 
v:minimal

if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 (
  ECHO ------------------------------------------------------------
  ECHO ******     THIS PROJECT HAD ERRORS DURING BUILD      *******
  ECHO ------------------------------------------------------------
  pause
)

TIMEOUT 4
EXIT
```

NOTE: if your project contains "." periods in the project name then they must be substituted with "_" underscores. In the above example the projects name is "MySolution.WPF.UI" but has been passed as in input parameter as "MySolution_WPF_UI" **ALSO** be aware that visual studio will save all files in your project prior to a build so before you build with a script like this you should use

```
CTRL + SHIFT + S
```

to save your projects, otherwise if you have recently added or removed files from your project they may not be referenced in the build. Also note you must have msbuild in your environmental PATH variables for this to work